# Inverse of stereographic projection of a circle on a line

Tags: differential-geometry, stereographic-projections

I am curious about the stereographic projection of the unit cycle centered at $0$, from the ''north pole'' $(0,1)$ on the line $y = -1$. We know: $$\phi: S_1/ \{(0,1)\} \to \mathbb{R}$$ can be given by $\phi(x,y) = \frac{2x}{1-y}$. I am trying to find its inverse. That is, given $u \in \mathbb{R}$ find $(x,y) \in S_1/ \{(0,1)\}$

Comment: Parametrize the line passing through $(0,1)$ and $(\lambda,-1)$, for instance as $c(t) = (1-t)(0,1) + t(\lambda,-1)$.
Now, solve the 2nd order polynomial equation $|c(t)|^2 = 1$: you should get two solutions, one of which is $t=0$, the other one $t({\lambda})$ giving the solution $\phi^{-1}(\lambda) = (1-t(\lambda))(0,1) + t(\lambda)(\lambda,-1)$ that you are looking for.